# Updating ListView on property change

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am having a strange problem in my UWP application.
I have a `ListView` bound to an `ObservableCollection<SomeInterface>`. I am changing one property of all the items in the `ObservableCollection`. The problem is that because of the `ObservableCollection` does not take a class as the type argument, rather it takes an `interface`, I cannot figure out how to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` on the `interface`.

So I went ahead and changed the property of all items in the collection ( without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` ). This is giving weird behavior. When I change the property ( I do this as soon as I navigate to the page containing the `ListView` ) It only affects only those `ListView` items that are not in view currently ie, if there are 100 items in the `ListView` and I can see the first 10 without scrolling down then those 10 items are unchanged but when I scroll down, I see that other (other than the first 10) `ListViewItem`s are reflecting the changes that were made. And to add to this, when I scroll up again ( to the first 10 items ), I see that now they are also changed.

to summarize, only the items that are not currently in the view get updated.

here's my code to update the `ObservableCollection`:

```
class SomePage : Page
{
    private ObservabeCollection<SomeInterface> SomeObservableCollection { get; set; } = new ObservabeCollection<SomeInterface>();
    ...
    private async Task ModifyObservableCollection()
    {
        var response = await MakeApiCall();
        var facets = response.ListOfItems;

        foreach (var item in SomeObservableCollection.ToList())
        {
            var fromApi = facets.author.FirstOrDefault(i => i.key == item.key);
            if (fromApi == null) continue;

            var itemInList = SomeList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.key == fromApi.key);
            itemInList.read = fromApi.read;
            itemInList.num = fromApi.num;

            //here!!
            itemInList = SomeObservableCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.key == fromApi.key);
            itemInList.read = fromApi.read;
            itemInList.num = fromApi.num;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind AuthorFacets, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewDataTemplate}"                         
        SelectionMode="Multiple">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListView>
```

My itemtemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewDataTemplate"
              x:DataType="local:ISomeInterface">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}"/>               
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind num}"/>             
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You'll have to do two things. First, implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the class that owns the read and num properties (and actually fire the PropertyChanged event when the property values change). Second, add `Mode=OneWay` to the `x:Bind` declarations, because the default is `OneTime` (or change it to `{Binding ...}`).

Comment: The `ListView` by default has virtualization on. Since you are using `OneTime` bindings, plus w/o INPC, already realized listview items simply won't be updated; however, for those which are going to be realized, they will be populated with new data, for the very first time. Make sense?

Comment: why does this work when I scroll down and again up ?

Comment: @Clemens, the problem is that I give the type of observablecollection as an interface (not a class, because there are many classes implementing that interface), in such case where do I implement `INPC` ?

Comment: In the class that implements your interface. It may implement more than one interface at a time, i.e. yours and INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Because as you scroll down, those listview items are recycled with new data; when you scroll up, same thing, listview items get recycled again with **new** data. This is all caused by virtualization. But doing this is very wrong. You need to implement INPC with one-way bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}"/>               
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind num}"/>
```

to

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read, Mode=OneWay}"/>               
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind num, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

And implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and it should work. By default, x:Bind is OneTime unlike traditional binding (because performance / memory) so your items in view won't update.

Without INPC? You could possibly try calling Bindings.Update() on the parent view after changing the properties, though you may lose scroll position.